# Align items at top, center and bottom is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div with a image at left then some info at right (a span, a h3 and another span). And I want that the first span at the right of the image positioned at the top, the h3 at the center and the other span at bottom. But this is not working.  Also at the right of the separator div I have a link that I also want to position at bottom and a span that I want to position at center.

Do you know where is the issue?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ct1ghpk2/2/

Html:

```
 <div class="item">
    <img src="">
    <div class="item_info">
      <span class="align-t">Span aligned at top</span>
      <h3>Title aligned at center</h3>
      <span class="align-b">Span aligned at bottom</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item_separator"></div>
    <div class="item_details">
      <span>Span aligned at center</span>
      <a href="">Link aligned at bottom</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
.item{
  background-color:white;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 10em;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.item img{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item_info{
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex-basis: 64%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.item_info .align-t{
  color:gray;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item_info h3{
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item-info .align-b{
}

.item_separator{
  height:100%;
  width:1px;
  background-color:red;
}

.item_details{
  flex-basis: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item_details span{
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color:gray;
}

.item_details a{
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `.item-info` a height of 100% so it is the full height of its parent. Then you can add the flex box property `justify-content: space-between;` to `.item-info` to make the content within the div be spaced how you're wanting.

```
.item-info {
    #yourStyles
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

See [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more details on css flex box and the properties available to you while using it.

As for the `.item-details`...

```
.item_details{
    #yourStyles
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item_details span{
    #yourStyles
    margin-top: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`justify-content: flex-end;` for a column makes the content start at the bottom and go up... adding a 25% top margin to the span inside that div will give you the spacing you're looking for on top while having everything else pushed to the bottom.

Comment: this is not a accurate solution for .items_details

Comment: @Bhawna I made the changes suggested above in the jsfiddle provided by the OP and it worked fine for me. The span (which they want in the center) and the link (which they want at the bottom) is in the proper place. Let me know what you mean by "accurate" solution.

Comment: I am sorry the fiddle I sent above was different. I edited. Can you share one fiddle with the solution you provided

Comment: If you want to see the difference the code I suggested makes you can just copy/paste the 4 lines of code I put in my answer into whatever jsfiddle you're looking at. Everything else is already in the fiddle shared by the OP. I am driving rn so I can't make the changes again and save them in a public fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you demanded must be like this as per my understanding.

The changes I made are in this.

```
.item_details{
  flex-basis: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.item_details span{
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color:gray;
}

.item_details a{
  font-size: 0.85em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ct1ghpk2/6/